# How to use intermediate results ( without extra cell) in excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got the following formula

```
=RANDBETWEEN (1,20) + (E2>15)*(RND()>30)*RANDBETWEEN(1,3)
```

this is the formula in `E2` which starts at 0; i would like to check the first `RANDBETWEEN()` value and if it is above `15` add to it a random integer betweent `1` and `3` .. How can i do it (store intermediate results without using a macro or have an additional cell in my report) ? CAN i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using standard Excel formulas. You could do it using Laurence Longre's MOREFUNC xll addin functions SETV and GETV
http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english/#Functions

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the [LET function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999)

```
=LET(num, RANDBETWEEN(1,20), IF(num > 15, num + RANDBETWEEN(1,3), num))
```